# How can i Remove the empty space from this image and crop it to the fish only - using openCV and python?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

[image: Fish Colour extract image]

How can i remove the empty space in this image and crop it to the part where there is the colored fish is.

Tried matplotlib, numpy etc, im new to this and dont have much knowledge. If there is any other library i can use and easy to use do let me know.

Comment: Define "improve empty space"!  Threshold and invert. Apply morphology to fill in holes. Then get contours. Then get bounding box of contours. The crop to the bounding box dimensions.

Comment: Better use grabcut().

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you mean by *"remove empty space"*. If you mean to get the upright (i.e. non-rotated) bounding box, it is as simple as this:

- make a greyscale copy of the image because it is simpler and faster to process
- threshold to pure black and white, then invert because `boundingRect()` will look for a white object on a black background
- find the bounding rectangle in the black and white image and draw it on coloured image.

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

# Load image and make inverted, greyscaled version
im = cv.imread('fish.jpg')
grey = cv.cvtColor(im, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, grey = cv.threshold(grey, 200, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cv.imwrite('DEBUG-grey.jpg', grey)   # debug only

# Get coordinates of bounding rectangle, print and draw in red onto original image
x,y,w,h = cv.boundingRect(grey)
print(f'x: {x}, y: {y}, w: {w}, h: {h}')
res = im.copy()
cv.rectangle(res,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),5)
cv.imwrite('result.jpg', res)
```

**Output**

```
x: 799, y: 92, w: 2658, h: 1895
```

[image]

---

If you want the exact mask of the fish, you need to work a little harder and maybe use `GrabCut()`. That might look like this - which just follows on directly after code above:

```
# The remainder implements GrabCut to get exact outline
mask = np.zeros(im.shape[:2], dtype=np.uint8)
fgModel = np.zeros((1, 65), dtype="float")
bgModel = np.zeros((1, 65), dtype="float")

# Save our bounding rectangle in format GrabCut wants
rect=x,y,x+w,y+h
mask, _, _ = cv.grabCut(im, mask, rect, bgModel,fgModel, iterCount=10, mode=cv.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)

# Make GrabCut mask into alpha channel so it controls opacity/transparency
alpha = np.where(mask==mask.max(), 255, 0).astype(np.uint8)
cv.imwrite('DEBUG-alpha.png', alpha)   # debug only

# Merge alpha channel into image so it goes from BGR to BGRA, and save to disk
res = np.dstack((im,alpha))
cv.imwrite('result.png', res)
```

**Output**

If you switch to StackOverflow's *"Dark Mode"* you can see that the areas immediately adjacent to the fish that were white above have now become transparent.

[image]

This is the alpha/opacity mask.

[image]

Comment: Mark, what is "dark mode" and how to enable it?

Comment: @fmw42 Hi Fred. You click your profile beside your score at the top of the SO screen just to the right of the "Search box". Then you click "Settings" under your photo then you should see "Dark Mode" under "Site Settings->Preferences". I'll Email you a picture

Comment: @fmw42 While you are there, you can usefully click *"Hide left navigation"* to get rid of useless junk on left side of your screen too :-)